# Return only value without function name in Scala

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I am new to Scala. I am trying to return a value from some scala code in Spark and I also get the function name along with the result. for ex executing below

```
def getHistory() : Long = {
    1 + 1
}
getHistory()
```

returns

```
getHistory: ()Long
res140: Long = 2
```

The additional information that is being returned seems to be a function of REPL as someone mentioned below. How can I turn this feature off so that I only see `2` being returned.

Comment: You are returning just `2`, the rest is only some helpful text provided by your REPL. I'm not sure to understand your question.

Comment: Thank you, I am not familiar with REPL, that gives something to work with. I have modified the details. How do I configure REPL to not return the helpful text?

Comment: If you don't want the REPL text then don't run your code in the REPL. Instead, you can can put you code in a `main()` method, compile the file, and invoke the compiled program. Seek out a good beginners tutorial for the details.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to see REPL text you can set it to `:silent` but then you won't see anything that isn't sent to STDOUT.

Here's a sample session:

```
%> scala  #start the REPL
Welcome to Scala 2.13.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.11).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :silent

scala> def two() = 1 + 1

scala> two()

scala> print(two())
2
scala>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the first comment on your post suggest, "the additional stuff" that you obtain is just the verbosity of the REPL.

You function indeed only return the value 2.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/repl/overview.html

Comment: Thank you, I am not familiar with REPL, that gives something to work with. I have modified the details. How do I configure REPL to not return the helpful text

Answer (score 0):

The REPL cannot be configured in the exact way that you want. (Why do you even want to configure it that way? What is your motive? The question is puzzling.)

Regardless, you can use `println` to produce "bare" output:

```
scala> println(getHistory())
2
```

Comment: Trying to execute some scala scripts(not a jar) through certain API and then consume the result. the current API result is in the form of a json with that whole `helpful text + result` being returned as a string. All I need is the actual result without the helpful text.